# how to auto hide intellisense on vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

When i am typing the intellisense info is not hidding.

[image]

How I can make it auto-hide after a few seconds?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your pointer hovering over an identifier? That would trigger a *tooltip*, which is like IntelliSense, but different.

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed this problem by adding this on my user settings.

```
"editor.parameterHints": false
```

The hinting stills works, but not that intrusive, it will just go away after you type the whole words.